# Tableview - Disclosure Indicator

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've set the cell accessory to "disclosure indicator" and I have linked that cell with an ctrl - click ("show (eg. push)") to another view. But when I test the app, the cell just becomes grey and nothing more (look at the screenshot). I want this to behave like a Settings-like view.

any hints?

thx, Tim

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Can you put the storyboard connection's screenshot ?

Comment: Control-click on your cell, and see if the segue is connected to  "Selection", or  "accessory action". It should be the former.

Comment: @rdelmar thank u! :) can u post ur answer so can i accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `disclosure indicator`is just that; an indicator, not a button, so when you make a segue from a cell , with or without a `disclosure indicator`, it needs to be a "selection" segue. The "accessory action" section of the choices you get when making the segue should be use if you have a "detail disclosure" button, and you want the segue triggered by touching the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to navigate by code means try this method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //navigateTo your viewController        
}
```

You can find this in TableView Delegate.